# No speedup with many slow cores?

Tags: c++, openmp

my C++ program calculates lots of features for 3D points. This takes a while, so I do the calculations in different threads. At the end all features (of all threads) have to be stored in one file.
On my local machine the multithread-implementation was a great success (4 threads -> runtime reduced by 73%).
However, on my server (40 slow 2GHz cores, 80 threads) it's even slower than on my local 4 threads.
Runtimes:

- Local 1 Core: 7.5 minutes
- Local 4 Core: 2 minutes
- Server 80 Threads: 3.1 minutes (slower than my local 4 cores)
- Server 20 Threads: 6.2 minutes
- Server 4 Threads: 4.75 minutes (Interesting - it's faster with less threads)

My code is appended.
I tried:

- Making the critical part smaller/faster by building a string within each thread and only writing it to file within critical part: No improvement
- Only writing the results to disk at the very end: No improvement (thought it could be Disk I/O)
- Using schedule(guided) for OpenMP-Loop for bigger chunk sizes: No improvement

```
      ...
      std::vector<double*> points;
      for(unsigned int j = 0; j < xyz.size(); j++) {
        points.push_back(new double[3]{xyz[j][0], xyz[j][1], xyz[j][2]});
      } 
      ofstream featuresOut;
      featuresOut.open(...);
      ...
      KDtree t(&points[0], points.size()); // Build tree
      float batchSize = ((float)points.size())/jobs;
      unsigned int first = job * batchSize;
      unsigned int last = ((job+1) * batchSize) - 1;

      // Generate features
    #ifdef _OPENMP
      omp_set_num_threads(OPENMP_NUM_THREADS);
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    #endif
      for(unsigned int r = first; r <= last; r++) {
        if (r % 100000 == 0) {
          cout << "Calculating features for point nr. " << r << endl;
        }
    #ifdef _OPENMP
        int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
    #else
        int thread_num = 0;
    #endif
        double features[FEATURE_VECTOR_SIZE];
        if (!(ignoreClass0 && type.valid() && type[r]==0)) {
          double reference[3] = {xyz[r][0], xyz[r][1], xyz[r][2]};
          vector<Point> neighbors = t.kNearestNeighbors(reference, kMax, thread_num); // here we have a ordered set of kMax neighbors (at maximum - could be less for small scans)
          //std::vector<double> features = generateNeighborhoodFeatures(t, reference, kMin, kMax, kDelta, cylRadius);
          unsigned int kOpt = determineKOpt(t, reference, neighbors, kMin, kMax, kDelta); 
          generateNeighborhoodFeatures(features, t, reference, neighbors, kOpt, cylRadius, false, thread_num);
    #pragma omp critical
          {
            featuresOut << xyz[r][0] << "," << xyz[r][1] << "," << xyz[r][2] << ",";
            featuresOut << kOpt;

            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < FEATURE_VECTOR_SIZE; j++) {
              if (isfinite(features[j])) {
                featuresOut << "," << features[j];
              }
              else {
                cout << "Attention! Feature " << j << " (+5) was not finite. Replaced it with very big number" << endl;
                featuresOut << "," << DBL_MAX;
              }
            }
            featuresOut << ",";
            if (type.valid()) {
              featuresOut << type[r];
            } else {
              featuresOut << 0;
            }
            featuresOut << endl;
          }
        }
      }
```

Only writing to disk at the very end (aggregated results of threads) does not solve the problem (see answer of @J.Svejda). Also keeping one KDtree for each thread results in no speedup.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know `openmp` but could it be that you have a lot of synchronization between the different threads? If so, do you really need to share info between the threads? Ideally, if the 20 threads could work with their part of the problem without any synchronization (and ideally without false sharing) you should be able to get close to the full performance gain of having 20 threads. Synchronize once and then start a new (with the same threads, parked in a pool).

Comment: When building the `KDTree`, you give the address of the pointer to the first point. How can it access the other points? It may not be the source of the slowdown, but there is definitely something wrong here.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: I am also new to openMP. I tried with schedule(static,10000), so the junk size for each thread is 10.000 loop iterations. Additionally I replaced the critical-section at the end - so the threads don't have to wait for each other (see my answer to @j-svejda )

The points are stored in a vector (so next to each other in memory). Knowing the size and the starting point should be enough. This code is build on top of a big library. There it was already used like that in examples...

Working on a smaller example to reproduce this

Comment: Big iron like that always has a NUMA architecture.  The processor interconnect can easily become a bottleneck if you don't intentionally limit concurrency so these threads can execute on the same processor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of your critical section. The time to write to disk usually takes much more than to compute something on the CPU. I don't know what complexity the work you do on the KDTree has, but writing to disk can take milliseconds, whereas instructions on CPU are in the order of nanoseconds. Though the data probably does not get flushed to `featuresOut` until you send an `endl`, it would explain your poor scaling. The critical section just takes too long and threads have to wait for each other.

Maybe increase the number of work per thread, say a thread does 5% of the points.
And then it would output to the file aggregated data from more points. See if it improves the speedup.

Comment: Double-checked it: It's not disc I/O latency. I build an array of stringstreams with size of the number of my openMP threads. So each thread just outputs its results to its own stringstream (for this test only the first feature and an endl). At the very end, all stringstreams are written to disk. No improvement.
I also set a fixed (big) chunk size for the parallel for-loop. Also no improvement.

Tried with one KDtree per thread -> No improvement (even a little slower).